# How would I go about differentiating t with respect to x?

Tags: derivatives

$$t=\frac{x}{v}+\frac{\sqrt{(\frac{a}{2})^2+(a-x)^2}}{(\frac{v}{3})}$$

We haven't covered how to differentiate equations like this yet. How would I go about finding dt/dx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sneaky way around some of the work others have suggested. In particular, you don't need to know how to differentiate the square-root function.

Do a little rewriting via algebra:
\begin{align}
t&=\frac{x}{v}+\frac{\sqrt{(\frac{a}{2})^2+(a-x)^2}}{(\frac{v}{3})}\\
t-\frac{x}{v} &=\frac{\sqrt{(\frac{a}{2})^2+(a-x)^2}}{(\frac{v}{3})}\\
\frac{v}{3}\left(t-\frac{x}{v}\right) &=\sqrt{(\frac{a}{2})^2+(a-x)^2}\\
\left(\frac{v}{3}\right)^2\left(t-\frac{x}{v}\right)^2 &=(\frac{a}{2})^2+(a-x)^2
\end{align}
Now remembering that $t$ is really $t(x)$, a function that varies with $x$, we have a equality between two functions -- one on the left, one on the right. So their derivatives must be equal. The one on the left needs the power rule and the chain rule; the one on the right needs only the power rule. Differentiating, we get
\begin{align}
2\left(\frac{v}{3}\right)^2\left(t-\frac{x}{v}\right)\left(\frac{dt}{dx} + \frac{-1}{v}\right) &=2(a-x)(-1)\\
\left(\frac{v}{3}\right)^2\left(t-\frac{x}{v}\right)\left(\frac{dt}{dx} + \frac{-1}{v}\right) &=(x-a)\\
\left(t-\frac{x}{v}\right)\left(\frac{dt}{dx} + \frac{-1}{v}\right) &=(x-a)\left(\frac{3}{v}\right)^2\\
\frac{dt}{dx} + \frac{-1}{v} &=\frac{(x-a)\left(\frac{3}{v}\right)^2}{t-\frac{x}{v}}\\
\frac{dt}{dx} &=\frac{(x-a)\left(\frac{3}{v}\right)^2}{t-\frac{x}{v}} + \frac{1}{v}\\
\end{align}

At this point, you have a formula for $\frac{dt}{dx}$, but it involves $t$, which may seem objectionable to you (or your teacher). Fortunately, you started out with a formula that expresses $t$ in terms of $x$, and can plug that in to get 
\begin{align}
\frac{dt}{dx} &=\frac{(x-a)\left(\frac{3}{v}\right)^2}{t-\frac{x}{v}} + \frac{1}{v}\\ 
&=\frac{(x-a)\left(\frac{3}{v}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{x}{v}+\frac{\sqrt{(\frac{a}{2})^2+(a-x)^2}}{(\frac{v}{3})} \right)-\frac{x}{v}} + \frac{1}{v}\\
&=\frac{(x-a)\left(\frac{3}{v}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{(\frac{a}{2})^2+(a-x)^2}}{(\frac{v}{3})} \right)} + \frac{1}{v}\\
\end{align}

and there's your answer without using anything other than the chain rule and the (integer) power rule and a bit of algebra. It can, of course, be simplified via a bit more algebra, but I leave that to you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Treat $a$ and $v$ as constants. To differentiate this, you will need to use the chain rule. To start, differentiate $\frac x v$ to get $\frac 1 v$, and then note that $\frac 3 v \sqrt{\left(\frac a 2\right)^2+(a-x)^2}=\frac 3 v f\big(g(x)\big)$, where $g(x)=\left(\frac a 2\right)^2+(a-x)^2$ and $f(u)=\sqrt u$. Then apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Addition plus square roots plus chain rule.

The chain rule tells how to
differentiate a function of a function:

$(f(g(x)))' = g'(x) f'(g(x))
$

Example:

Since
$(x^2)' = 2x$
and
$(\sqrt{x})' = \dfrac1{2\sqrt{x}}
$,
so
$(f(x)^2)' = 2f'(x)f(x)$
and
$(\sqrt{f(x)})'
=\dfrac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)}}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
(\sqrt{(\frac{a}{2})^2+(a-x)^2})'
&=((\frac{a}{2})^2+(a-x)^2)'\dfrac1{2\sqrt{(\frac{a}{2})^2+(a-x)^2}}\\
&=\dfrac{2(a-x)'(a-x)}{2\sqrt{(\frac{a}{2})^2+(a-x)^2}}\\
&=\dfrac{-2(a-x)}{2\sqrt{(\frac{a}{2})^2+(a-x)^2}}\\
\end{array}$